# Removing Custom Domain in Github

Tags: r, git, web, github

I want to remove custom Domain from Github. Any help, please.

[image]

Actually I want get https://myaseen208.github.io/DiallelAnalysisR/ rather than http://www.myaseen208.com/DiallelAnalysisR/ as given the following picture.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As illustrated in [`isaacs/github` issue 1213](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1213) (which shows a similar problem), you should have a `CNAME` file

But not in: [`github.com/MYaseen208/DiallelAnalysisR`](https://github.com/MYaseen208/DiallelAnalysisR)

In the repo [`github.com/myaseen208/myaseen208.github.io`](https://github.com/myaseen208/myaseen208.github.io) (same as [in the issue 1213](http://www.myaseen208.com)): this [`CNAME` file](https://github.com/myaseen208/myaseen208.github.io/blob/d5d68c5f1b9e6cb5545f4e6cea8f6c21687db63d/CNAME), which does include:

```
www.myaseen208.com
```

> **Apparently your user's GitHub domain automatically comes from your `{username}.github.io` repo**

Start by [removing that file](https://github.com/myaseen208/myaseen208.github.io/commit/64367b5ca73f9ceafcd2da76e42c46e5b1132af2), and see if that changes anything (wait a bit, and [clear your browser local cache](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1213#issuecomment-412367254))

Comment: Wow, this guy knows his stuff!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. I resolved it by emptying the custom domain field, then entering a space in the same field so that you can activate the save button (Note: the save button will not let you save if the field is empty).

After you hit save, your page will reload and you will be able to see this again

[image: Custom domain removed]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the content of the text box and press “Save”

Comment: Thanks @Jesse for your answer. Yes, I did that and saved. But still it shows the same web domain.

Comment: Is there a file in your repository named “CNAME”? If so, delete it.

Comment: I could not find any file with name CNAME.

Comment: Ask Github support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your user name's GitHub domain back which automatically comes from your `{username}.github.io` repo then simply empty the custom domain input field and enter a space in the custom domain field in order to activate the save button as the save button will not let you save until the field is empty.

Hit save & your page will reload and you will see your static site live on your Github username domain.

[image]