# How to remove custom domain from github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I integrated a custom domain from `namecheap.com` but now when I am trying to do default github pages hosting this domain name is coming (`anuragportfolio.me`) in between the full domain name. Previously it was coming as `https://anurag30112003.github.io/Portfolio.github.io/`. How to remove it or restore to default?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Custom Domain in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123013/removing-custom-domain-in-github). You can also take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#removing-a-custom-domain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need remove anuragportfolio/anuragportfolio.github.io repo that include the cname.