# Pages on my GitHub using custom domain instead username.github.io

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I try using GitHub pages to deploy my website

[GitHub pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPb61.png)

I don't know what is causing this and I have already tried searching all setting related to GitHub pages on my account but still can't fix it.

I thought this problem is related to my GitHub student pack, because my account is connected to Namecheap and I bought a domain there and I am using InfinityFree as hosting (and parked my domain in InfinityFree). But I can't find setting about this.

Comment: note, i already try set to /root and still using custom domain

Comment: SOLVED, CNAME FILE ON username.github.io
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123013/removing-custom-domain-in-github

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Custom Domain in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123013/removing-custom-domain-in-github)